# How to add shipping phone number paypal order v2 api

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I want to add phone number in shipping address but i couldn't find in paypal documentation of order v2 api.When i checked paypal order api v1 documentation shipping phone number was available but in v2 i couldn't find.
In paypal order v2 api in shipping variable it has only address_line_1, address_line_2, admin_area_1, admin_area_2, postal_code,country_code but in paypal order v1 it has additional variable phone to add shipping phone number.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the billing phone number:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/invoicing/v2/#definition-billing_info

Comment: bro i'm using order api not invoice api.

Answer (score 0):

The `phone` in the `payer` object https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders-create-request-body

Comment: i already try this but  in transaction details under ship to it show address and below address it show user paypal phone number not payer given number.

Comment: That's because they are allowed to select a different one, and indeed it will default to the one from their account.

Comment: how i will add given phone number with shipping address so that it will show our phone given phone number and not paypal default phone number

Comment: Set `shipping_preference` in the `application_context` or check your syntax or you can't do it

Comment: i also already set the shipping_preference to SET_PROVIDED_ADDRESS and it showed given shipping address but i was unable to add shipping phone number along with shipping address in shipping address it  showed user paypal default phone number.

Comment: check your syntax, if it's wrong it will be ignored

Comment: i already double checked syntax.but if there were a problem with syntax then paypal will not allow to process payment so i think my syntax is corrrect.